# Adding text to text Edit while the loop( while true is running)

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I have a while loop which is set to True , inside the loop I want to write some text to TextBrowser but no matter what I try , self.textEdit.setText or self.textEdit.append doesn't work.
I tried to change also  label or even line text but without success.
when I take this out of the while loop the text appear in the text browser.
I treid using Threads but even when the thread is started the text does not appear in the text browser.  here is the code i have.

```
import socket
import socket as socket_library
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1014, 920)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 180, 141, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.radioButton.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 230, 691, 411))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                    "color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 80, 571, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Server"))

            self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                          "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00557f;\">Lots of Trips Server</span></p></body></html>"))
            self.radioButton.clicked.connect(self.check_readio_button)


    def check_readio_button(self):
            if self.radioButton.isChecked():
                self.activate_server()


    def activate_server(self):

            hostname = socket.gethostname()
            IPaddress = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
            port = 45971

            server_socket = socket_library.socket(socket_library.AF_INET, socket_library.SOCK_DGRAM)


            server_socket.bind((IPaddress, port))
            while True:

                try:
                    message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)

                except ConnectionError:
                    print("Connection with server is closed.")
                    break

                server_socket.sendto("Thank you for connection.".encode("UTF-8"), address)

                answer = message.decode("UTF-8")

                self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.task(), args=(None,))
                self.thread1.start()
                self.thread1.join()

            server_socket.close()


    def task(self):
        self.textEdit.setText("This is from another thread")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    Thread.start()
    Thread.join()
```

Comment: Append to list and join them at last...Write at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "append" is working, but you need to process pending events and refresh the GUI by calling `QApplication.processEvents()`